# Can I install Windows 8 Media Center Pack on multiple computers

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-media-center, media

I am upgrading multiple computers with Windows 8 upgrade. they have an option now to get the Windows 8 Media Center Pack for free. Do I need to get three separate keys, or will one suffice for all the computers. I was also curious if I need three separate emails to do that. Any suggestions are appreciate. I will say, I did fill out the form at Microsoft for the media pro pack and they said I need to wait 24 hours, but it has been a few days and I have yet to see it. Any comments on that. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- You need 3 separate keys
- The key should come in a few days. It took a week for me. Just wait and see